# Проверить, подписан ли юзер на группу в ВК и FB

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, facebook, facebook-api

Возможно ли с помощью JavaScript проверить на странице сайта, подписан ли пользователь на группу в ВК и FB этого сайта?

Необходимо для pop-up окна с призывом подписаться на группу сайта, чтобы юзерам которые уже подписаны на эту группу, не показывать это pop-up окно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример как это сделать для Facebook, только нужно заменить ID приложения + получить разрешение на login, для этого нужно его отправлять на проверку модераторам Фейсбука.
https://yadi.sk/i/VNi49n7Rh9dj7

`https://jsfiddle.net/maxK/an63Lmu5/`
Основной код - лог в фейсбук и получение подписки на группу:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    //do whatever you need to do after a (un)successfull login         
    if ( response.status == 'connected' ) {
        console.log( response );        
        // make the API call 
        FB.api(
            "me/likes/19292868552",
            function (response) {
                console.log( response );
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                        alert('You are liked FB Page!');
                    } else {
                        alert('You are not liked FB PAGE!');                        
                    }
                // handle the result 
                }
            }
        );  

    }

}, { scope: 'user_likes' });
```

Comment: И это работает только для групп, для страниц не работает вроде.

Comment: наоборот. работает для страниц, не работает для групп..

Answer (score 0):

Да, используй API соц сетей и проверяй группы, в которых состоит юзер. Но для этого ему придется авторизоваться в нужной соц сети на твоем сайте.